# Modifying dictionary values while iterating with dict.values() or dict.itervalues()

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a dicionary that is initialized like so:

```
tab = {'Mike': 0, 'Chad': 15, 'Taylor': 2}
```

I want to be able to add integers to each value in the dictionary.
For example, after adding 5, the dictionary should look like this:

```
{'Mike': 5, 'Chad': 20, 'Taylor': 7}
```

It seems as if this can be done with a couple of lines of code but I can't figure it out.
I've tried a for loop:

```
for k in tab.itervalues():
    k = k + 5
```

I run this code and then print out the dictionary:

```
tab = {'Mike': 0, 'Chad': 15, 'Taylor': 2}
```

The dictionary has undergone no change. I'm not sure if Python recognizes the values as strings or integers.

Comment: The line `k = k + 5` is actually creating a brand new variable. You can't see it because python hides it from you (this is part of python's pass-by-object paradigm). However that's neither here nor there. Even if you *could* modify k, it won't modify the dictionary. See the answer by waffle paradox for the correct approach.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way?

```
for k in tab.keys():
    tab[k] += 5
```

Comment: Honestly I find tab.keys() more readable, but yes that would work as well.

Answer (score 7):

`tab.itervalues()` creates an iterator over values.

You iterate over these, and are handed each value in turn. The values are `int`s. **In Python, these are immutable**.

In Python, the statement `a += 3` is translated - in **most** cases - to `a = a + 3`. `a + 3` creates a **new** int object, for the case where `a` already referred to an int, and then the name `a` is rebound to the new object.

So you alter the iteration variable (by rebinding it), but not the value in the map (because it is immutable).

[waffle paradox's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852831/7851470) gets around this by using an iterator over keys to access and then rebind the values inside the dict. This is simple and Pythonic and fine.

Alternately, you can **embrace immutability**, and apply the functional programming paradigm. We want to create a dictionary that is like the one we have but with the keys incremented; and causing `tab` to refer to this new dictionary is only incidental.

Thus:

```
tab = dict((k, v + 5) for (k, v) in tab.iteritems())
```

This approach will often make your life easier when you have a harder problem based on the same fundamental issue.

Comment: My natural inclination would have been to mutate the original dict.  I like the alternate approach and I will try to keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: Nowadays we can write the much prettier `tab = {k: v + 5 for k, v in tab.items()}`.