# Can't replace string values in a list of dicts when iterating with dict.values()

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to remove some words from strings that are in a list of dicts.

Here are the values:

```
titles = [{'03': 'MONTHLY PRODUCTION OF OIL PALM PRODUCTS SUMMARY FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019'},
          {'06': 'PRODUCTION OF CRUDE PALM KERNEL OIL FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019'},
          {'07': 'PRODUCTION OF PALM KERNEL CAKE FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019'},
          {'08': 'REFINERY : MONTHLY PRODUCTION OF SELECTED PROCESSED PALM OIL FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019'}]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
for i in range(len(titles)):
    for title_name in titles[i].values():
        title_name.replace(' FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019', '')
```

Calling titles again shows that values have not been changed.

Expected result:

```
[{'03': 'MONTHLY PRODUCTION OF OIL PALM PRODUCTS SUMMARY'},
 {'06': 'PRODUCTION OF CRUDE PALM KERNEL OIL'},
 {'07': 'PRODUCTION OF PALM KERNEL CAKE'},
 {'08': 'REFINERY : MONTHLY PRODUCTION OF SELECTED PROCESSED PALM OIL'}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying dictionary values while iterating with dict.values() or dict.itervalues()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852819/modifying-dictionary-values-while-iterating-with-dict-values-or-dict-itervalue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code changes the variable `title_name`, not the dict value.
try

```py
for d in titles: # loop all dicts in "titles"
    for k in d.keys(): # loop all keys in dict from "titles"
        d[k] = d[k].replace(' FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
titles = [{'03': 'MONTHLY PRODUCTION OF OIL PALM PRODUCTS SUMMARY FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019'},
 {'06': 'PRODUCTION OF CRUDE PALM KERNEL OIL FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019'},
 {'07': 'PRODUCTION OF PALM KERNEL CAKE FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019'},
 {'08': 'REFINERY : MONTHLY PRODUCTION OF SELECTED PROCESSED PALM OIL FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019'}]


for i in range(len(titles)):
    for title_name in titles[i]:
        title_name_temp = titles[i][title_name].replace(' FOR THE MONTH OF JUNE 2019', '')
        titles[i][title_name] = title_name_temp

print(titles)
```